# how do size JPA to Criteriaquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteriaquery

I have this Java code:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(MyEntity.class))); 
cq.where(/*your stuff*/); 
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

I would like to do this a criteria query:

```
SELECT COUNT(p),pa.nomPays FROM SessionPersonne s JOIN s.personne p , 
p.entreprise e , e.adresse a , a.localite l , l.pays pa , s.session session 
WHERE size(s.passageCollection)  > 0   GROUP BY pa.nomPays
```

but how do `size(s.passageCollection)  > 0` with the critical query ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why is this tagged as java related?

Comment: because criteriaquery criteriabuilder and java are not ?CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(MyEntity.class)));
cq.where(/*your stuff*/);
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();

Comment: Please add your java code to your question, it will make it more easy to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: i want convert the JPA code to the criteriaBuilder i'm add the java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains everything very well. 
http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination

Just in case link breaks i'll add a segment and add where the where should be put too

```
int pageNumber = 1;
int pageSize = 10;
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(countQuery.from(Foo.class)));
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();

CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> from = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
CriteriaQuery<Foo> select = criteriaQuery.select(from);
select.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(fromRoot.get("entityColumb"), "bar")));

TypedQuery<Foo> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select);
while (pageNumber < count.intValue()) {
    typedQuery.setFirstResult(pageNumber - 1);
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    System.out.println("Current page: " + typedQuery.getResultList());
    pageNumber += pageSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the SIZE for use in Criteria as follows

```
Expression<Integer> sizeExpr = qb.size(SessionPersonne_.passageCollection)
```

hence

```
qb.greaterThan(sizeExpr, 0);
```